# Gooey Animation for Pager Indicator inside Item Decoration

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation, viewpagerindicator, item-decoration

Can some please teach me how to make a gooey pager indicator for on-boarding please?

I really am just curious on how these animations are done.

I am thinking of something like this [Here](https://material.io/guidelines/growth-communications/onboarding.html#onboarding-top-user-benefits).

Its the example under the [image: Google Material Design OnBoarding Example]. The image might not show it but the circle below combines into one forming a rounded rectangle by a gooey effect before the indicator circle slides to the next circle. After the circle has slide to the correct position, the formed rounded rectangle goes back to its original circular form.

Can someone give me an idea how this could be achieved? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can someone mind explain why i got a down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need https://github.com/chenupt/SpringIndicator. I've used this once on a project before. The documentation is kind of straight forward.

Comment: Thank very much. I don't really need a library to do it. I want to learn it myself but thank you for leading me where to start. I'd probaably ready the code in that library. :) This is the reason why I accepted your answer. :)